# Getting Webmock to stub HTTParty requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty, webmock

I am having trouble getting Webmock to work. I am using HTTParty to make GET requests.  I would like to have the following request return an error:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'api_parser'
require 'httparty'

describe ApiParser do
  describe "#get_data" do
    it "returns data" do
      stub_request(:get, "congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com").to_return(:status => [401, "Forbidden"])
      puts HTTParty.get "http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/bills/?history.enacted=true"
  end
end
```

I have added the following lines to spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'

WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

But it is still calling the actual API and not being stubbed.  I do not get the 401 error that I'm expecting.  I'm not sure what the issue is here.  Is spec_helper missing anything?

Update: I have done some testing and it looks like `require api_parser` is causing this issue.  The stubbing works when I remove it, but it stops working when I add it.  The ApiParser class is where I use HTTParty.  I modified the above test to use HTTParty directly instead of using the methods in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that I was disabling Webmock in my ApiParser class (forgot to remove it while doing some debugging a few hours ago), which was overriding the config in spec_helper.

Comment: This was actually a useful answer, as I was having similar problems, and it made me consider if WebMock was also unexpectedly disabled, somewhere.